# Handle Promise Catches in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, axios

I have a promise based API service that requests data from my backend. It also comes with it's own error catch, so I don't have to write it everywhere. When it's written like this:

**BackendService.ts**

```
...
getTasks() {
    return axios.get('/api/tasks')
        .then((response) => {
            const {
                tasks
            }: {
                tasks: tasksType
            } = response.data;
            return tasks;
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
...
```

**Entries.tsx**

```
...
const getTasks = () => {
    backendService.getTasks()
        .then((tasks: tasksType) => {
            const filteredTasksData = filterAPIDataForState(tasks);

            addTasks({
                tasks: filteredTasksData
            });
        })
}
...
```

I get the following error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(tasks: tasksType) => void'
is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void | tasksType) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.Types of parameters 'tasks'
and 'value'
are incompatible.Type 'void | tasksType'
is not assignable to type 'tasksType'.Type 'void'
is not assignable to type 'TaskInterface[]'.
```

I guess this is because of the catch, that could make the Promise return nothing (because of the console.log). If I give the `getTasks` from `Entries.tsx` it's own catch handler and remove it from BackendService.ts `getTasks`, it works.

Shouldn't Typescript be able to tell that the `.then()` in `Entries.tsx` would not run if there was an error, since there's already a catch handling this situation?

Comment: In *BackendService.ts* you are returning *tasks* variable which is not a promise. If you want to extract the data use *await* or a function inside the *Axios .then()*. See [Promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). See the [Axios example](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) and choose which is the most suitable method for you and your project. PS: Since you are using Typescript i suggest you to choose *await*.

Comment: @CarloCorradini from what I see in the [Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) (see the chaining code), you can return a variable and the following `.then()` will be able to work with it.

Comment: Try with [this](https://pastebin.com/nL98Tsrc). @Yousaf as far as I can see there is no promise returned :\

Comment: @CarloCorradini: That's the way promises work. **ANYTHING** returned inside a `.then()` is wrapped inside a Promise. Similar to anything returned inside a function marked with the `async` keyword returns a promise. Therefore `return tasks` returns a promise of tasks. Please read up on how promises and async/await work

Comment: `tasks` may as well be void, so how could you be sure it's of type `taskType`? it works the way it should.

Comment: @CarloCorradini your example code is not valid. Try running [this code example](https://pastebin.com/ZDFKnmDf) and see what gets logged on the console. Make sure `axios` is installed before you run this code. Also try [this code example](https://pastebin.com/h0WxsWHc)

Comment: "*It also comes with it's own error catch, so I don't have to write it everywhere.*" - that's not how it works, no.

Comment: @RafiHenig That's the whole point of the question, how to avoid/ handle this problem

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I am not sure if it works this way, I just thought it would. Is there a way to not write a duplicate catch/ error handler everytime I call the method?

Comment: @Vincent No, there's not. You *must* consider the case that `getTasks()` returns nothing (in case of an error) on every individual call, and handle it appropriately (e.g. showing error messages to the user) or forward the error. If many of these handlers do the same thing, you can of course share code by passing the same function to each `.catch()`.

Answer (score 6):

> the .then() in Entries.tsx would not run if there was an error, since
> there's already a catch handling this situation?

That is not entirely correct.

`catch` block in `getTasks` method in `backendService.ts` file is returning `undefined` and **when a `catch` block returns a value** instead of:

- Throwing a value
- Throwing an error, or
- Returns a promise that is rejected

instead of invoking the `catch` block in the calling code, **`then` block is invoked**.

This happens because the `Promise` returned by the `getTasks` method in the `backendService.ts` file depends on the following:

- If the `Promise` returned by `axios.get(...)` fulfils then what you do in the `then(...)` block
- If the `Promise` returned by `axios.get(...)` is rejected then what you do in the `catch(...)` block

In your case, if the `Promise` returned by `axios.get(...)` fulfils, then `then(...)` block will execute and since it just returns the `tasks`, `Promise` returned by `getTasks` method in `backendService.ts` file fulfils, leading to the invocation of the `then(...)` block in the calling code, i.e. in `Entries.tsx` file.

If the `Promise` returned by `axios.get(...)` is rejected, `catch(...)` block will execute. Since `catch(...)` block in `getTasks` method is just logging the error, `Promise` returned by `getTasks` method will **fulfil with the value of `undefined`** which will lead to the invocation of **`then(...)` block in the calling code**, i.e. in `Entries.tsx` file.

See the following example to understand this.

```js
function getData() {
  // incorrect url which will lead to response.ok being false
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todo/1';
  return fetch(url)
          .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
              return response.json();
            } else {
              throw new Error();
            }
          })
          .catch(error => console.log('catch block in getData function')); 
}

getData()
  .then(data => console.log('then block ran'))
  .catch(error => console.log('error block ran'));
```

In the above code snippet, as API URL is not correct, `response.ok` in the `then` block is false, so error is thrown from the `then` block which is caught by the `catch` block in the same function. As this `catch` block is just logging a message and implicitly returning `undefined`, `Promise` returned by the `getData` function fulfils with the value of `undefined`. So instead of the `catch` block, `then` block executes in the code that calls the `getData` function.

If you didn't know this then you might be surprised to see this behavior but that is how promises work with `catch` blocks. The reason for this behavior is that if you have a promise chain that has more than one `catch` block, like shown below:

```
fetch(...)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...)   
  .then(...)
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

then if the first `catch` block catches an error that is thrown from any of the methods chained before it, then this `catch` block can do one of the following two things:

- throw the error which then will lead to the invocation of the next `catch` block in the promise chain
- handle the error and return some value

If the first `catch` block returns normally, the promise returned by `catch` block will fulfill with that return value of the `catch` block and this value then becomes the input of the callback function of the next `then` block in the promise chain. So the promise chain continues instead of stopping as soon as first `catch` block executes.

---

Coming back to your code, when the `catch` block executes in the `getTasks` method in `backendService.ts` file, it logs the message and returns `undefined` which then leads to the invocation of the `then` block in the `Entries.tsx` file, instead of the `catch` block and that is why you get a complaint from typescript about your code.

**Solution**

You can use one of the following options to solve this problem:

- Throw the error caught in the `catch(...)` block of `getTasks` method in `backendService.ts` file so that `Promise` returned by `getTasks` method is rejected instead of fulfilling with the value of `undefined`.
- Remove the `catch` block in the `getTasks` function in `backendService.ts` file and add the `catch` block in the code that calls `getTasks` method.

In my opinion, there's no need for a `catch` block in the `backendService.ts` file because if the `Promise` returned by `axios.get(...)` is rejected, `Promise` returned by `getTasks` method will also be rejected if there's no `catch` block in the `getTasks` method. So just remove the `catch(...)` block from the `getTasks` method and add the `catch(...)` block where you are calling this `getTasks` method.

Comment: thank you for your response! I implemented the second solution and just log the error to the console. This is the first time I have seen these multiple catch blocks, but from what you wrote it makes sense to me that it is done this way.

Comment: This is a common confusion in Promise.
Whoever tried to find a way for axios requests to "just popup a message and stop executing the following handlers in case of a failure", endup making a statement in their coding standard document: "There MUST be a catch at the end of each call."

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to handle this

1. In BackendService.getTasks() just remove .catch() and handle .catch() in the Entries.getTasks()
2. In BackendService.getTasks() add another then and return with empty tasks for example .then(it => it || [])

Axios won't crash when response error so you must check response properly and handle it as it should be not just destruct response object blindly

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. If I handle it like the first solution, the catch will have to be implemented everytime the backendService.getTasks() gets called. Is there a way to prevent this? Can you maybe explain the reasoning behind the second solution?

Comment: The options 2 is just return empty tasks when error.
But as I said Axios won't crash when response error so you must check response properly and handle it as it should be not just destruct response object blindly.
So you won't need .catch() in the first place.